# Preference Screen adding a entity header

Tags: android, android-preferences

How can I add such called "**Entity Header**" in a PreferenceScreen like listed in the docs here:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/settings/settings-guidelines#entity_header
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/settings/settings-guidelines#user_education

I can't find any element in Jetpack Preferences or other resource how I can add such header inside the PreferenceScreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *Entity header* preference built in. You have to create your own.

1. Create a xml file with your own Entity header design. This is a file in res/layout folder. In my case:
   **entity_preference.xml**:

   ```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/md_theme_light_secondaryContainer"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:paddingVertical="16dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/entity_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/entity_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.HeadlineSmall"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/entity_description"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.BodySmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Brief description"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Use that custom design in your Preference screen. In my case this is a xml file in res/xml:
   **preference_screen.xml**:

   ```
    <EditTextPreference
        app:key="title_text"
        app:title="Title"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
   ```

   [...]

[Result preference screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhAZK.png)